# Flex container with two columns; second column has four rows

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am having difficulty displaying the following layout in flex. I have 5 boxes and I want to divide my container in two, displaying one box vertically and the other 4 vertically.

[image]

Here's my CSS:

```
.trades, .trade-panel {
    flex: 1;
 }
.layout-4-5 {
    flex-direction: column;
}
.layout-4-5 > div {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Then I set the basis of the fourth or last child to 100%.

```
.layout-4-5 > div:nth-child(1) {
    flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

And here's my HTML

```
<div class="trades layout-4-5">
  <!--trade-panel are my individual boxes --->
  <div class="trade-panel">
    </div>

</div>
```

Above print my layout horizontally. Considering My `flex-direction` is `column` and my first child or box has a 100% basis, shouldn't that print what I want? Please any help would be appreciated.

Note: Since the boxes are of equal size, the column containing the four other boxes should be longer, provided they are in the arrangement above, its ok. tq

Comment: Add the first div in one container and other four in another container.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on your question or code. But here's a general solution:

```css
flex-container-1 {
    display: flex;                   /* establish flex container */
    flex-direction: row;             /* flex items will align horizontally */
    justify-content: center;         /* center flex items horizontally */
    align-items: center;             /* center flex items vertically */
    
    /* for demo purposes only */
    height: 250px;
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #777;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

flex-container-1 > flex-item {
    height: 90%;
    flex: 0 0 45%;                   /* <flex-grow> <flex-shrink> <flex-basis> */
    margin-right: 8px;               /* a bit of space between the centered items */
    border: 1px dashed #333;
    background-color: yellow;
}

flex-container-2 {
    height: 90%;
    flex: 0 0 45%;
    display: flex;                   /* flex item is now also flex container */
    flex-direction: column;          /* items will stack vertically */
    justify-content: space-between;  /* align items vertically */
}

flex-container-2 > flex-item {
    flex: 0 0 22%;
    border: 1px dashed #333;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<flex-container-1><!-- main container -->

    <flex-item></flex-item><!-- flex item #1 (first column) -->
    
    <flex-container-2><!-- flex item #2 / nested flex container (second column) -->
    
        <flex-item></flex-item>

        <flex-item></flex-item>

        <flex-item></flex-item>

        <flex-item></flex-item>

    </flex-container-2><!-- close nested container -->
    
</flex-container-1><!-- close main container -->
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jv7tsLwh/)

Answer (score 1):

I struggled and struggled on this one and then serendipitously discovered a new solution to this problem *right* as I had decided to give up and use floats. I was finally able to get this to work without using separate DIVs for columns.

UPDATE: I have simplified my previous version of this by having the height specified on .items.

1. Provide non-percentage `width` and `height` to `.items`.
2. Use `flex-direction: column` on `.items`.

CSS:

```
.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 40em;
  height: 20em;
}

  .item:first-child {
    width: 20em;
    height: 20em;
    background-color: black;
  }

  .item:nth-child(2) {
    width: 20em;
    height: 5em;
    background-color: pink;
  }

  .item:nth-child(3) {
    width: 20em;
    height: 5em;
    background-color: blue;
  }

  .item:nth-child(4) {
    width: 20em;
    height: 5em;
    background-color: yellow;
  }

  .item:last-child {
    width: 20em;
    height: 5em;
    background-color: red;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="items">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div><!-- .items -->
```

Codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZXoqJJ

Comment: This solution will not work if you have dynamic content (variable height content).

Comment: Exactly, I had the same idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have give margin and background color property so you can better understand.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">
       <div class="flex-harshad">
         <div class = "flex-harshad2">  
            Harshad
         </div></div>
    </div>

    <div id="right">
       <div class="flex-harshad">
        <div class="flex-item">world</div>
        <div class="flex-item">by</div>
        <div class="flex-item">Alan</div>
        <div class="flex-item">Dong</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is css.

```
body,
div {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0 none;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body,
#wrapper,
#left,
#right {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden; 
}

#left { 
  float: left; 
}

div.flex-harshad2{    
    margin : 5px;
    margin-top : 25px;   
    min-height: 91%;
    background : white ;
    width : 90px;        
}

div.flex-harshad{
    background: red;
    height : 100%;   
    width : 100px;
    text-align: center; 
    display : inline-block; 
    background :orange ;
    margin :10px;  
}
div.flex-item {
  background: white;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-top : 25%;
  min-height : 20%;; 
  /* remove text-lign will not center text itself */
  text-align: center;   
}
```

Here is output :

[image]

Comment: The question asked for a flex solution. This is a float solution.

Comment: @Michael_B sometimes what people want, and what people ask, are entirely different.

Answer (score -2):

```css
flex-container-1 {
    display: flex;                   /* establish flex container */
    flex-direction: row;             /* flex items will align horizontally */
    justify-content: center;         /* center flex items horizontally */
    align-items: center;             /* center flex items vertically */
    
    /* for demo purposes only */
    height: 250px;
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #777;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

flex-container-1 > flex-item {
    height: 90%;
    flex: 0 0 45%;                   /* <flex-grow> <flex-shrink> <flex-basis> */
    margin-right: 8px;               /* a bit of space between the centered items */
    border: 1px dashed #333;
    background-color: yellow;
}

flex-container-2 {
    height: 90%;
    flex: 0 0 45%;
    display: flex;                   /* flex item is now also flex container */
    flex-direction: column;          /* items will stack vertically */
    justify-content: space-between;  /* align items vertically */
}

flex-container-2 > flex-item {
    flex: 0 0 22%;
    border: 1px dashed #333;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<flex-container-1><!-- main container -->

    <flex-item></flex-item><!-- flex item #1 (first column) -->
    
    <flex-container-2><!-- flex item #2 / nested flex container (second column) -->
    
        <flex-item></flex-item>

        <flex-item></flex-item>

        <flex-item></flex-item>

        <flex-item></flex-item>

    </flex-container-2><!-- close nested container -->
    
</flex-container-1><!-- close main container -->
```

Comment: This appears to be just a copy of the code that was submitted in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36800877/17175441