# Flexbox 3 divs, two columns, one with two rows

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to take

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Three sequential divs and turn it into below. Where red is div 1, green is div 2, blue is div 3.

I can do this with floats, something like

```
.div1 { float: left; }
.div2 { float: left; }
.div3 { float: left; }
```

But I can't seem to get it working in flexbox, is this possible?

[image]

Comment: It's simple if you can set a fixed height on the container. Otherwise, no, it's not possible natively with flexbox. You would need an ugly hack.

Comment: See this post for an explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34480760/3597276

Comment: Or possible with nesting.. but then there would be more than 3 divs.

Comment: @ZimSystem, yes, if that's an option, that's a good solution. Simply wrap the two items on the right in a container, which becomes a sibling to the left item. Done.

Comment: here is a float example http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ZLKmLm used for an answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41797496/responsive-flexbox-layout-wrap-issue/41797709 (flex and grid are also options (for 3 siblings) only grid will allow to let height aside ... but not really yet avalaible :(

Comment: I've added an alternative solution to this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46658205/4682834

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**The Legit Method:**
*Recommended

```css
.flex-row {
    flex-direction: row;
    display: flex;
}

.flex-column {
    flex-direction: column;
    display: flex;
}

.flex-body {
    display: flex;
}

.flex-body div:not([class*="flex"]) {
    border: 1px solid white;
    flex: 1 1 200px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-body">
  <div class="flex-row">
    <div style="background: #0980cc;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-column">
    <div style="background: #09cc69;"></div>
    <div style="background: #cc092f;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**The Hackish Method:**
*Not Recommended (I'm sure you'll notice why)

```css
.flex-body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-content: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
}

.flex-body div {
    border: 1px solid white;
    height: 300px;
    flex: 1 1 200px;
}

.flex-body div:last-of-type {
    flex: 1 1 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-body">
  <div style="background: #0980cc;"></div>
  <div style="background: #09cc69;"></div>
  <div style="background: #cc092f;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: and how to do it in a reputable way as table?

Comment: @Macilias Look at row-spans, for columns that need to span more than one row. The rest should be pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 10):

After thinking about this a little more, it is possible with flexbox. The container just has to have a defined height (`%`, `px` or `vh`) will work.

http://codeply.com/go/U1DCKAx85d

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.a {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  background: red;
}

.b, .c {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  background: green;
}

.c {
  background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `flexbox` is very simple, you just need a container for these three `div` elements.

Let's define a div with a `.box` class and add the `div` elements. Also let's add three classes for the colors: `.red`, `.green` and `.blue` and two classes to handle the columns `left` and `right`.

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="left red"></div>
    <div class="right green"></div>
    <div class="right blue"></div>
</div>
```

Now we define the `box` class as a flexbox:

```css
.box {
    display: flex;
    ...
}
```

Then we define the direction as `column` (vertical) and if it can be flowed `wrap`:

```css
.box {
    ...
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    ...
}
```

Also, we can define the dimensions of the `div` elements. `left` will be `45%` of the parent `width` and `100%` of the parent `height`.

```css
.left {
    width: 45%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

While `right` will be `55%` of the parent `width` and `50%` (half) of the parent `height`.

```css
.right {
    width: 55%;
    height: 50%;
}
```

Full example:

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
}

.red {
  background: #cc092f;
}

.green {
  background: #09cc69;
}

.blue {
  background: #0980cc;
}

.left {
  width: 45%;
  height: 100%;
}

.right {
  width: 55%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="left red"></div>
  <div class="right green"></div>
  <div class="right blue"></div>
</div>
```