# Bootstrap 4 Flexbox force rows to fill vertical space inside col

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I am trying to build a video player in Bootstrap 4 using two columns, one containing the video, and the other containing rows with a thumbnail and title. The problem I am having is that the rows are not filling the vertical space of their parent column. What is the correct way to use flexbox helper classes to create a right column that will fill the vertical space regardless of how few items there are? or is there a more efficient way to do this in `Bootstrap 4`?

This is the desired layout I am looking for
[image]

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <!-- Main video player -->
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/730x411">
    </div>

    <!-- Video Selector -->
    <div class="col col-sm-4 d-none d-sm-block ">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 bg-warning"><img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/730x411"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 bg-success">Video One</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 bg-warning"><img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/730x411"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 bg-success">Video Two</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Bootstrap **4.1.0**, the [Flex grow utilities are included](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#grow-and-shrink). Just change the 2nd column to `<div class="col col-sm-4 d-none d-sm-flex flex-column">`, and then add `flex-grow-1` to the rows. The rows on the right will auto fill the height.

https://codeply.com/go/CaJxOgoFHX

```
<div class="col col-sm-4 d-none d-sm-flex flex-column">
    <div class="row flex-grow-1">
        <div class="col-sm-3 bg-warning"><img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/730x411"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 bg-success">Video One</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row flex-grow-1">
        <div class="col-sm-3 bg-warning"><img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/730x411"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 bg-success">Video Two</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row flex-grow-1">
        <div class="col-sm-3 bg-warning"><img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/730x411"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 bg-success">Video Three</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row flex-grow-1">
        <div class="col-sm-3 bg-warning"><img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/730x411"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 bg-success">Video Four</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: This uses Bootstrap 4.1.0 which includes the `flex-grow-1` class.

---

Related: [Flexbox 3 divs, two columns, one with two rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43056180/flexbox-3-divs-two-columns-one-with-two-rows/43131022#43131022)

Comment: Where would you put the flex classes to center the row>div contents vertically?

Comment: You could use `d-flex align-items-center` on the cols like this: https://www.codeply.com/go/DEl8GAh160

Answer (score 3):

#### Bootstrap version >= 4.1.1.

On its parent, add the `d-flex` and `flex-column` classes. That means you must remove the `d-sm-block` class because in the presence of `d-sm-block`, `d-flex` does not work. And then, add the `flex-grow-1` to the two `row`s.

---

#### There are two rows here and they take half of the available space.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <!-- Main video player -->
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/730x411">
    </div>

    <!-- Video Selector -->
    <div class="col col-sm-4 d-none d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="row flex-grow-1">
        <div class="col-sm-3 bg-warning"><img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/730x411"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 bg-success">Video One</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row flex-grow-1">
        <div class="col-sm-3 bg-warning"><img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/730x411"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 bg-success">Video Two</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Check this [pen on codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YLQVva) or run the code snippet.

---

#### There is one row here but still it takes all the available space.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <!-- Main video player -->
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/730x411">
    </div>

    <!-- Video Selector -->
    <div class="col col-sm-4 d-none d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="row flex-grow-1">
        <div class="col-sm-3 bg-warning"><img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/730x411"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 bg-success">Video One</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

FYI, If you want that one of the rows takes as much space as it needs and the other takes all the available space, use `flex-grow-1` on the latter one only.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
<!-- Main video player -->
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/730x411">
        </div>

<!-- Video Selector -->
        <div class="col col-sm-4 d-none d-flex flex-column">
            <div class="row flex-grow-1">
                <div class="col-sm-3 bg-warning"><img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/730x411"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-9 bg-success">Video One</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-sm-3 bg-warning"><img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/730x411"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-9 bg-success">Video Two</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

#### Bootstrap version 4.

Bootstrap version 4 does not have the `flex-grow-1` class. In that case, use the code below.

```css
.flex-grow-1 {
  -ms-flex-positive: 1 !important;
  flex-grow: 1 !important;
}
```