# One div on the left side and two divs on the right side

Tags: html, css

I have a little problem. I'm trying to program such a layout with HTML and CSS:

[Here's the picture of what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuLnn.jpg)

I looked at this question:
[Flexbox 3 divs, two columns, one with two rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43056180/flexbox-3-divs-two-columns-one-with-two-rows) . The only problem is that you can't give the divs a margin without them destroying the layout.

If the left image is higher, then the two right images should use the remaining space. (There are only a few boxes that I tried to place correctly first. I wanted to do the styling privately, so do not wonder.)

Here is my code what I have tried so far (Press full page. In this little window you can only see the mobile version):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#showroom {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red; /* To see showroom Background */
  padding: 1em;
  display: flex;
}

#boxOne {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: grey;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}

#showroom #boxTwo {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: grey;
  margin: 10px;
}

#showroom #boxThree {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: grey;
  margin: 10px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  #showroom {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  #showroom #boxOne, #showroom #boxTwo, #showroom #boxThree {
    height: 33.3%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="showroom">
  <div id="boxOne"></div>
  <div id="boxTwo"></div>
  <div id="boxThree"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: is this the end HTML or can you change a bit?

Comment: @AristeidisKaravas what would you add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

To make the `#boxOne` wider, we should look at the grid parent, which we are saying is 3 columns wide, with each column representing `120px`.

Now let's look at `#boxOne` for a second, and catch/fix an error I introduced.

```
#boxOne {
  grid-column: 1; /* Oops—this is wrong */
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}
```

We declared the grid to be 3 columns, yet `#boxOne` is only spanning a single column. The other boxes are also spanning a single column. Here's what our grid looks like now.

[image]

You can see that we're not even using that third column. Let's adjust `#boxOne` to span twice as wide as the other boxes. One really important detail is to count from the *first vertical line*. Think of the column like this:

[image]

Now it should be clear what we need to do.

```
#boxOne {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  …
}
```

The other boxes we'll place at the span place where `#boxOne` left off.

```
#boxTwo {
  grid-column: 3;
  …
}

#boxThree {
  grid-column: 3;
  …
}
```

Now things are looking the way we want.

[image]

---

I would approach this using CSS Grid. In your example, the images would implicitly take up the necessary space, and you wouldn't need to use `px` values in the line declaring `grid-template-columns`. In your case, you could replace `120px` with `1fr` which is a fractional unit utilized by CSS Grid.

Another advantage of using CSS Grid is that you can avoid a lot of additional `width` and `height` settings, as well as using margins for the gaps between items.

```css
#showroom {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 120px);
  gap: 1rem;
}

#boxOne {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

#boxTwo {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

#boxThree {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

#showroom > * {
  background-color: #444;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="showroom">
  <div id="boxOne"></div>
  <div id="boxTwo"></div>
  <div id="boxThree"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for. But is there a way to make  **ONLY** the boxOne wider? If so how would that work with the grid system? Sorry, i'm a `Grid` noob

Comment: @JustChillinInDaHood I've updated the answer for you and included some needed explanation for how to think of the grid.

Comment: i'm so so sorry but do you know how to make it responsive? With a page width of 750px all boxes should have a width of 100% and all should be the same height so about 100px. I am so sorry to bother you `@media screen and (max-width: 750px){}`

Comment: @JustChillinInDaHood I would take what you have thus far and create a new question.

Comment: Thanks that's a good idea